# What data is returned from SSRS to ReportViewer web control

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a need in my current project to access SSRS reports. However, due to security reasons, management does not want to integrate SSRS reports from the web server. What they prefer is to have some kind of middle layer. So the webserver should talk to the middle layer and request the report, the middle layer connects to the SSRS server, gives the report to middle layer, middle layer gives it to webserver.

I looked at Fiddler to see how report viewer on webserver requests a report from SSRS. It gets the report via a get. How can I make this happen? Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Reporting Services is powered by a webservice that you can tap into directly.  Here's the start of that rabbit hole:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx